# Importing laptop as gift in France, how much duty will I have to pay?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, electronic-items

I will fly into France from the U.S. with my personal laptop.  I also want to take a new one as a gift for my hostess.

Will I have to pay a tax duty on it?

Comment: Probably. How much is the laptop worth?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you'll be liable to pay 20% VAT on a new laptop if its value is greater than €430 euro in to France from outside the EU customs area. On the plus side, there's no specific duty to pay (see "Ordinateur portable" on [this page](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/articles/a10798-calcul-des-droits-et-taxes-sur-les-achats-a-l-etranger))

You could try and just walk through the "nothing to declare" aisle anyway - but you'd then be smuggling and at some risk of facing penalties.

Comment: Just VAT? Is there no import duty specific to electronics?

Comment: No duty for Laptops into the EU (I looked into this a ~18 months ago when buying a laptop - and the US had cheaper options than the UK. But once the 20% VAT was added...)

Comment: You are indeed right. Here's an authoritative reference for you: http://www.douane.gouv.fr/articles/a10798-calcul-des-droits-et-taxes-sur-les-achats-a-l-etranger (scroll down for an informative table).

Comment: Thanks, just been looking for a good reference, and bouncing around lots of offical pages tellin you what you need to do for goods to declare, but nothing about what items are effected by said decleration.

Comment: Your answer is not consistent with the page you are linking to. The French VAT for laptops is 20% (not 19.6%) and you are allowed to bring goods with a value up to 430€ (not 20€) when entering France by air without having to pay VAT or other duties.

Comment: (+1) Probably doesn't make a difference in this case but I think the rule for VAT are much more complex.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Oops, confused the limit on having something shipped to you without paying import VAT with the limit on what you can carry.

Comment: @CMaster: Where do you have the 390€ limit from? As I wrote in my comment, the value limit is 430€ (btw. uniform for the enitire EU and not specific for France).

Comment: Errr, probably from also having open the UK customs page at the same time, and seeing the value there in £s.

Answer (score 0):

Before bringing a laptop from the USA as a present, consider that it has the wrong keyboard, the wrong power plug, you need to make sure that it works with 220 Volt, the receiver may have a hard time getting warranty repairs, and the receiver will *not* have any EU consumer rights.

Comment: All good points but perhaps more appropriate for a comment? Also, it might actually be precisely the right keyboard and one reason why the recipient would appreciate the present. I order them myself within the EU but I have used strange keyboards in foreign countries to be able to write my native language and some other languages more easily ;-)

Comment: The wrong plug can also be rectified for <€5. You can buy a cable with the right plugs on both ends from lots of places.

Comment: In addition some vendors offer worldwide warranty.

Comment: And, like the keyboard, it could be the case that it is the **right power brick**, not the wrong one. For instance, if you buy a Thinkpad in Europe, you get it with a 3-prong, grounded power brick, which is more cumbersome to use in different countries than a US-bought 2-prong power brick + a 5€ Europlug cable.

Comment: It's particulally worth noting that US keyboards are not just printed differently from the various EU ones, they also have one less key.