# Do I have to declare my new laptop when leaving?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paris, electronic-items, san-francisco

I know I have to declare my newly purchased laptop from San Francisco when I land in Paris. Do I have to declare it when I am at the airport of San Francisco as well? Or can I declare it while being on the airport of San Francisco *only*?

Comment: @KateGregory I am thinking of *buying a new laptop in SF*.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49773

Comment: In most US airports, most of the time, you have to remove your laptop from your bag for the x-ray machine at airport security.  There's no customs screening on departure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing laptop as gift in France, how much duty will I have to pay?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49773/importing-laptop-as-gift-in-france-how-much-duty-will-i-have-to-pay)

Comment: No it's not a dupe of that, since the dupe says that when you land in Paris, *then* you declare it in the customs. I am asking whether I should declare it in San Francisco's customs too...

Comment: There is no exit customs in the USA. The only reason I know of _(and it does not apply here)_ is if you had a high-value object on which duty is usually paid in the United States, and you want to register the serial number with Customs so that on return to the United States there is no issue about paying duty on it again.

Comment: Then @AndrewLazarus, this could serve as an answer. :)

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but becauseful buying electronics in the US and taking them home to [not US] For example WIfi, DVD, and a few other things are region protected and may not work right once your back home. It's more of an annoyance then anything else, but thought I should mention it.

Comment: @coteyr good point! For example, just the plug-in is different! ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no exit customs for ordinary travelers in the USA. The only reason I know of *(and it does not apply here)* is if you had a high-value object, like imported photographic equipment, on which duty is usually paid in the United States, and you want to register the serial number with Customs so that on return to the United States there is no issue about paying duty on it again.

Answer (score 7):

Customs is generally about the *importation* of goods— barring illegal items and assessing duties on legal but taxable ones.

The U.S. has no formal exit controls, and U.S. Customs and Border Protection (CBP) does not perform any standard outbound inspection of airline passengers departing the U.S. Even if you had something to declare, you would have no place to declare it.

The airline will care insofar as they need to know if anything you have cannot legally be taken aboard an aircraft (e.g. weapons, fire starters), but a laptop is not much of a concern.

Yes, it is illegal to take many things out of the country— say, [eagle feathers](https://www.fws.gov/eaglerepository/factsheets/PossessionOfEagleFeathersFactSheet.pdf), or [some cryptographic technology](http://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/regulations/export-administration-regulations-ear), or things controlled by international treaty like counterfeit products or drugs. But the list of those items is not large enough, nor the likelihood of a random passenger carrying them, to justify the resources needed for passenger-level inspections from the U.S. Instead, the authorities will X-ray or hand-inspect checked luggage, and only interact with you if there is a suspicion of wrongdoing.

Besides, even if you bought the laptop new in San Francisco, it was probably imported from Taiwan or South Korea in the first place.

Comment: Since the page you link to concerning cryptographic export restrictions also concerns Windows 2000, I suspect it does not reflect the [current state of affairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States).

Comment: @phoog Fair enough, just linked to the EAR directly.

Comment: So you agree with Lazarus, good!

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, but I am leaving the answer up as we cover slightly different background.

Comment: Not that an X-ray would help discover cryptographic technology.